# Continue after exception or Error in Rest Api call using OAuth2RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, exception, custom-error-handling

i am making a rest call using Spring Oauth2RestTemplate. I am trying to catch any exception while trying to make a restAPI call and continue the flow of Exception.

Two ways i tried:
**Way I(Using try catch).**

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> getResponse(URI uri, HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
            Object obj) {

    ResponseEntity<Object> response = null;
    try {
        response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<>(obj, httpHeaders),
                Object.class);

    } catch (Exception serverEx) {
        LOGGER.error("ERROR while calling API.Full Exception: ",serverEx);
        response.getBody().setLink(object.getUrl());
    }

    return response;
}
```

**Way II(Custom Handling).**

```
public class RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {

 private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler.class);

@Override
public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {
    return (httpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == Series.CLIENT_ERROR
            || httpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == Series.SERVER_ERROR);
}

@Override
public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse) {
    //Log The Error but contibue the flow
}
}
```

But neither way the execution gets stopped. I want to continue the flow of the execution. if the call fails i want to handle it and continue the flow. Can any one please suggest whats happening here?

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream.
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:131)
at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:118)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:139)
at org.springframework.web.client.MessageBodyClientHttpResponseWrapper.hasEmptyMessageBody(MessageBodyClientHttpResponseWrapper.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:82)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:932)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:916)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:663)
... 223 more
```

Error Response OutboundJaxrsResponse{status=500, reason=Internal Server Error, hasEntity=true, closed=false, buffered=false}

Any suggestion on this please?

Comment: this `response.getBody().setLink(object.getUrl());` will throw null pointer exception

Comment: @Deadpool may be. But the execution itself is not coming to catch block. Execution of the application without coming to catch block.It returns 500.

Comment: does this log prints ? `LOGGER.error("ERROR while calling API.Full Exception: ",serverEx);`

Comment: @Deadpool No.I am not seeing the log. :( up[dated the question with error.

Comment: place debug point in `catch` block and try, controller should enter that catch block

Comment: @Deadpool nope. i tried to keep the dubug point but no luck :(